# What will be region

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given $|z-1|<|z-5|$ where $z$ is complex number. Now i know when $|z-1|=|z-5|$, this will be locus of points on perpendicular bisector joining points $1$ and $5$. But how do i solve with inequality sign

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By squaring,

$$(z-1)(z^*-1)<(z-5)(z^*-5).$$

This simplifies to

$$4z^*+4z<24$$

or

$$\Re z<3.$$

Answer (score 1):

Geometrically, this is a med-school problem:
the points with affix $z$ which satisfy the inequality are the points in the plane which are closer to $1$ than $5$, i.e; the points in the open half-plane which contain $1$. 
In termes of complex numbers, this half plane is defined by the inequation
$$ \operatorname{Re} z<\frac{1+5}2=3. $$

Answer (score 0):

The perpendicular bisector when using "$=$" comes from the interpretation "$z$ is as far from $1$ as it is from $5$". When using "$<$" instead, the interpretation is "$z$ is *closer* to $1$ than it is to $5$". The perpendicular bisector is still very relevant, but it's not the answer. Can you tell what the answer is?

Answer (score 0):

$z=Re(z)+iIm(z)=a+bi$ then by using the formula for the absolute value you get

$$|z-1|=(a-1+bi)(a-1-bi)=a^2-2a+1+b^2$$

and

$$|z-5|=(a-5+bi)(a-5-bi)=a^2-10a+25+b^2$$

$$a^2-2a+1+b^2<a^2-10a+25+b^2\Longleftrightarrow -2a+1<-10a+25\Longleftrightarrow 8a<24$$
$\Rightarrow a=Re(z)<3$

So when you have the equality, the bisector cuts the plane in half. 
Your solution now is the part of the plane, where $1$ lies in, the point from which you need the smaller distance